# getting an error : Argument 'ctrl' not defined in angular js

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap, angularjs-routing, angularjs-controller

my index.html file has the following :

```
  <script src="scripts/controllers/form/DashboardCtrl.js" />
  <script src="scripts/controllers/chart/morrisChartCtrl.js" />
```

my app.js file is as follows :

```
 return $routeProvider.when('/', {
        redirectTo: '/signin'
    }).when('/dashboard', {
        templateUrl: 'views/dashboard.html',secure: true
    })
```

My dashboard page is as follows :

```
    <div class="page page-dashboard" data-ng-controller="DashboardCtrl">

<div class="panel-body" data-ng-controller="morrisChartCtrl"> 
</div></div>
```

I can view the Dashboard page, but the morrisChartCtrl is not showing the chart.

My controller is defined as follows :

```
app.controller('morrisChartCtrl',  function($scope) {
$scope.mainData = [
  {
    month: '2013-01',
    xbox: 294000,
    will: 136000,
    playstation: 244000
  }];
});
```

So I am not able to figure out why myController is not being called

Comment: can you bring it in fiddle ?

Comment: You have an empty DIV with a controller and data but no output at all? Makes sense that nothing is displayed. Maybe put something like {{mainData | json}} in the DIV.

Comment: Hi, the DIV is not empty, I made a mistake while putting it here. I dont see anything on the browser